# How To Increase Maximum File Upload Size (PHP)?

Tags: php, web-applications, file-upload, php-ini

I am running a XAMPP server on my computer. The maximum file size I've uploaded is 24.3kb. My server fails to upload a 78kb file. I know because I get an empty $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] and an error when attempting to move the file.

I went into php.ini and changed the two variables: upload_max_filesize = 2M and post_max_size = 8M, both to over 100, although it should have worked at 2megabytes and 8 megabytes. Still no success.

I am a little new to php but I did enable all logs and I tried to check error logs but the only one with relevant information was the php error log and the only error I see is 'undefined index in file path/tp/myfile.php on line 13'. Any other error logs I should check?

I looked at a lot of forums and threads and I can't find why mine is not working.

[EDIT] I do have the right encryption type. (I DID after all get one image to upload).
enctype="multipart/form-data

[EDIT2] My php script:
Just incase your curious, this is an exercise in 'Head First php mysql'

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $score = $_POST['score'];
    $screenshot = $_FILES['screenshot']['name'];
    $target_directory = "images/$screenshot";
    $tmp_directory = $_FILES['screenshot']['tmp_name'];

    echo "echoing" . $tmp_directory;

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_directory, $target_directory) or die("Failed to move");

$db = "guitarwars";
$table = "highscoretable";

$dbc = mysqli_connect(privateinfor) or die("Failed to connect to server");
mysqli_select_db($dbc, $db) or die("Failed to select database");

$query = "INSERT INTO $table VALUES(0, NOW(), '$first_name', '$last_name', '$score', '$screenshot')";

//mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("Failed to query database");

}else{

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                width: 100%;
            }
            .container label{
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Guitar Wars - Add Your High Score</h1>
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="container">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="32768" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>
        <label for="first_name">First Name:</label> 
        <input type="text" size="32" maxlength="32" value="<?php echo $first_name; ?>" placeholder="First Name" id="first_name" name="first_name"/>
        <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label> 
        <input type="text" size="32" maxlength="32" value="<?php echo $last_name; ?>" placeholder="Last Name" id="last_name" name="last_name"/></br>
        <label for="score">Score:</label> 
        <input type="text" size="11" maxlength="11" placeholder="Enter score" value="<?php echo $score; ?>" id="score" name="score"/></br>
        <label for="screenshot">Screenshot:</label> 
        <input type="file" id="screenshot" name="screenshot"/></br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
        </div>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to change the memory_limit

```
memory_limit = value
upload_max_filesize = value
post_max_size = value
```

Comment: memory_limit = 128M. The 'M' stands for megabytes I'm pretty sure.

Comment: please check phpinfo() and see if they are getting updated. And also did you restarted your server?

Comment: I did not restart my server. But I just restarted my server with no luck. Values being shown on phpinfo(): post_max_size=100M, upload_max_filesize = 100m. memory_limit = 128M.

Comment: It still not allows you to upload? Are you getting timeout error or not?

Comment: Yeah, I pasted my php code above. I get 'echoingFailed To Move'. Meaning the temp directory is not echoed and I get the die() message. But for my tiny 27kb file, I get the tmp directory. eg. echoingC/directory. I don't know what a timeout error is but I hope this answered your question. the die() function executes (if that is what a timeout is).

Comment: Could you please also print_r($_FILES); and paste it's result here

Comment: Array ( [screenshot] => Array ( [name] => 489125.jpg [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 2 [size] => 0 ) ) echoingFailed to move. Incase it is relevant (I just checked it) I tried using a file with only lowercase letters to no avail.

Comment: The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.

Please remove:-

<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="32768" enctype="multipart/form-data"/>

Comment: @user2316667 I hope it answers your question. Please mark the question done.

Comment: Ah! I just parroted that line from my book. One question before you go for my own understanding if you would be so kind. HOW is this input limiting the file size? I didn't refer to it at all anywhere and I thought hidden input types were soley to return data for server convenience (like an id number to input/modify data).(and thanks too!)

Comment: When you post data back to server it encodes the form data and php server decodes it. So there are php form directives that control the data handling. You can also change MAX_FILE_SIZE name to of your choice in php.ini

Comment: No reference to MAX_FILE_SIZE in php.ini? But you are saying that there is a pre-defined function that looks for MAX_FILE_SIZE and that function overwrites the max sizes set in the ini? I'd appreciate if, as a last thing, you could tell me where I can go to change the name of 'MAX_FILE_SIZE' form data. So lets say, my server instead looks for 'MAX_SIZE' post data to restrict. Like I said, I could not find the reference to MAX_FILE_SIZE. Inner workings is really interesting to me. I appreciate it so so much!

Comment: Sorry I wrote it wrong that "You can also change MAX_FILE_SIZE name to of your choice in php.in"

I meant that you can change upload size settings in php.ini. The HTML form directive is that you can control it from HTML field rather than changing in php.ini. But as a security benefits just ignore it and change it through php.ini.

Comment: Also many servers won't allow this directives so don't depends on them.